# Is there a way to prompt an email send from sharepoint from a checkbox selection in infopath?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-server, email, infopath-rules

I have created a form that when submitted the status changes from blank form to submitted I would like to send an automated email when they submit it. Giving them direction for the next steps in the process. I would also like do be to send an email when a box is selected in the form, when their form is rejected (currently listed as a check box and in a drop down).

The form is a 2010 form published to a 2007 sharepoint :(

Any advice would be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new data connection to submit data as an email message and a new view with your message.  Then create a rule on submit that changes the view to your new email view and fires the email submit data connection.

As for the second scenario, aside from any customizations you want to include, you need to include in your rule a condition that prevents the email submit from firing if your checkbox is unchecked.